# how to tell if app was launched from closed or background on iphone?

Tags: iphone, multitasking

Hi all is there a specific delegate method which is called when an app is brought to the foreground from the background on ios? The reason being I want to perform different actions when my app is launched and when it is simply resumed from the background?

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're coming from the background, [applicationWillEnterForeground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is called.

When it starts "from closed", [applicationDidFinishLaunching:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidFinishLaunching%3a) is called.

Comment: ops sorry, didn't know there was a minimum on the time before closing